# Can Rails 6 with ActionCable implement long polling API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, long-polling, actioncable

I need to create an API for my rails project, and the API main purpose is to start actions that will run in background for some time (using ActiveJob).

I need the API client to be able to monitor the background job using long-polling. The client makes the request and if the job is still running, the request waits until some timeout to give the result, or returns earlier in casethe job has terminated in the meantime.

If I ware to design a full-stack application, I'd use ActionCable to notify the client when the job terminates. But here, I don't want to make public any ActionCable websocket API and I want to stick with plain HTTP.

Is it possible to use ActionCable to wait for messages on a channel in a Rails controller (server-side)? Can such controller cause a connection count limit, especially with postgresql connections (which I won't be using while I'm waiting on Redis for ActionCable messages)?